# Rewrite URL for reverse proxy

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

This is similar to [nginx url rewrite for reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095480/nginx-url-rewrite-for-reverse-proxy), but I don't know how I should apply that answer to my situation.

I am trying rewrite URLs for a reverse proxy, so that `/pathA/something` becomes `/pathB/something` when Nginx makes the request to the upstream server.

```
location ~ /pathA(/|$) {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    rewrite ^/pathA(.*) /pathB$1;
}
```

I tried this, but I get an Nginx 404 page (and *not* the example.com 404 page).

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but I think the rewrite should be on the top of the location block.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add redirect (302) or permanent (301):

```
location ~ /pathA(/|$) {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    rewrite ^/pathA(.*) /pathB$1 permanent;
}
```