# NGINX: Rewrite url and reverse proxy to a different port

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am having difficulty rewriting url and reverse proxy the request to a spring boot app. Rewrite works but i am losing port number and cause of that it is not working. For example
`localhost:80/order.pl` converts into `localhost/home`. The port gets lost and app is not receiving the request
[Similar examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095480/nginx-url-rewrite-for-reverse-proxy) online don't work.

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    set $upstream localhost:8050;

    location ~"^\/order.pl$"
    {
        rewrite "^\/order.pl$ "/home" permanent;
    }

    location /
    {
        proxy_set_header X - Forwarded - For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X - Real - IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30;
        proxy_send_timeout 30;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
        proxy_pass http: //$upstream;
    }
}
```

If I don't do rewrite, reverse proxy is working but with rewrite I am losing port number. Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx would not normally specify the port as part of an external redirect if the port number is the same as the default port for the scheme. Port 80 for `http` and port 443 for `https`.

You can specify the port explicitly in the rewrite statement.

For example:

```
location = /order.pl {
    return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/home;
}
```

*Note: I used `curl` to test this, as the browser dropped the port from the address-bar for exactly the same reasons.*